# Count words in Persian document correctly

Tags: xepersian, word-count, texcount

when I use the command `texcount filename.tex` in CMD, half-spaced words count two words instead of one word. How can I solve this problem? \Thanks

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
من می‌روم ز کوی تو و دل نمی‌رود
\end{document}
```

This example is 8 words, but latex counts it 10 words. Half-spaced used in `می‌روم` and `نمی‌روم` words. I have a lot of half-spaced words in different situation with another alphabet. Half space is U+200C (ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER) or in Persian standard keyboard is `Shift + Space`.

[Yas font link](https://fontlibrary.org/assets/downloads/yas/6d496aade0637f6ff0aed373a19aa54a/yas.zip)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple, but not very elegant, quick-fix for this. It requires modifying the TeXcount Perl script.

There is a line in the code of texcount.pl which defines the pattern for words.

> $NamedWordPattern{'words'}='(@+|@+\{@+\}|\{@+\}@+)([\-\'\.]?(@+|\{@+\}))*';

In version 3.1 it is at line 496, but should be the same line in all fairly recent versions of TeXcount. It's essentially a regular expression, but where `@` is later to be replaced by a regular expression matching letters. Essentially, it says that a word is a sequence of letters, but where the characters `-`, `'`, and `.` may be contained within it.

To add Unicode character `U+200C` to the list of characters permitted within a word, this line may be changed to

> $NamedWordPattern{'words'}='(@+|@+\{@+\}|\{@+\}@+)([\-\'\.\x{200C}]?(@+|\{@+\}))*';

where `\x{200C}` has been inserted. Admittedly, this is not a very elegant solution, and there may be other characters that should also be permitted within words.

A better solution could involve using Unicode character classes to identify separator characters that should be permitted within words, but I'm not sure what would be an appropriate rule: this would likely impact other languages with similar characters as well, which might give either a desired or undesired effect.